# Check for identical value in firebase collection

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How would you implement a matching system to check when two values are the same in one collection from different documents? This code has to call a function to run every-time it detects that the two values are matching.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Wouldn't this just be a matter of querying the collection for the value and if the returned snapshot count > 1 then there's a duplicate? Is there something more?

Comment: It has to find the duplicate value and then execute a function based on that document

Comment: Right. So what's the issue with writing that code? Or did you attempt it and are having an problem with the code? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) :

> Cloud Firestore provides powerful query functionality for specifying which documents you want to retrieve from a collection or collection group. These queries > can also be used with either get() or addSnapshotListener(), as described in Get Data and Get Realtime Updates.

I will recommend you to use a unique identifier for each entry and then you can add a  listener that will match each data from the collections.
Syntax :

> ```
>  query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
>     @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
>     if (dataSnapshot.exists()) { 
>     // dataSnapshot is the "issue" node with all children with id 0
>      for (DataSnapshot issue : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
>      // do something with the individual "issues"
> } } }
> ```

You can refer to the [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51002413/15774176) where Frank has explained it briefly with the following  function code.

> ```
> public interface AlreadyBookedCallback {
>   void onCallback(boolean isAlreadyBooked);
> }
>
> private void alreadyBooked(final String boname, final String bodept, final String botime, AlreadyBookedCallback callback) {
>     CollectionReference cref=db.collection("bookingdetails");
>     Query q1=cref.whereEqualTo("time",botime).whereEqualTo("dept",bodept);
>     q1.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
>         @Override
>         public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
>             for (DocumentSnapshot ds : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
>                 String rname, rdept, rtime;
>                 rname = ds.getString("name");
>                 rdept = ds.getString("dept");
>                 rtime = ds.getString("time");
>                 if (rdept.equals(botime)) {
>                     if (rtime.equals(botime)) {
>                         isExisting = true;
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>             callback.onCallback(isExisting)
>         }
>     });
> }
> ```

For more information you can also refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65590080/15774176) on how to check duplicate values in documents.

Comment: @chackerian posted an answer, Is it helpful?